# Problem uploading file through a patch request from axios

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

The challenge is with sending a patch request with an attachment to `Laravel` backend from a `Vue` `axios` request. I tried using  [objectToFormData](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform/blob/master/example/upload.html) to send a post request and it worked just fine. However, the same `objectToFormData` does not even send any fields from the form with a patch request.

**Template**

```
<template>
   <div> 
      <div id="medicalForm" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="acertLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-success">
                        <h4 class="modal-title text-white" id="acertLabel">{{ editMode ? 'Edit Medical Record' : 'New Medical Record'}} </h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    </div>
                    <form @submit.prevent="editMode ? updateRecord(): newFile()" id="inModal" enctype="multipart/form-data" @keydown="medicalForm.onKeydown($event)">
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Desciption <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text"  v-model="medicalForm.description" autocomplete="off" name="description" placeholder="describe document here" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': medicalForm.errors.has('description') }" >
                                <has-error :form="medicalForm" field="description"></has-error>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label v-if="!editMode">Choose File <span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
                                <label v-if="editMode"> Replace Existing File <span class="text-danger"> </span></label>
                                <input type="file" @change="handleFile" class="form-control-file" :class="{ 'is-invalid': medicalForm.errors.has('file') }">
                                <has-error :form="medicalForm" field="file"></has-error>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button v-show = "!editMode" type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">Create</button>
                            <button v-show = "editMode" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning waves-effect waves-light">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

**Script**

```
<script>

export default {
    name: 'Medical',
    data(){
        return {
            id: this.$route.params.id,
            medicals:{},
            editMode: false,
            medicalForm: new Form({
                'record_id': '',
                'user_id': this.$route.params.id,
                'description': '',
                'file': null,
            }),
        }
    },

    methods:{

        handleFile(e){

            let selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
            this.medicalForm.file = selectedFile;

        },


        updateRecord(){

           this.medicalForm.patch('/api/medicals/'+this.medicalForm.record_id, {

                transformRequest: [function (data, headers) {
                    return objectToFormData(data)
                }],

                onUploadProgress: e => {
                    //file is uploading
                }

            })
            .then(response => {
                //updated
            })
            .catch(errors => {
                //not updated
            });



        },

        newFile(){

            this.medicalForm.post('/api/medicals', {

                transformRequest: [function (data, headers) {
                    return objectToFormData(data)
                }],

                onUploadProgress: e => {
                    console.log('Saving your data...')
                }

            })
            .then(response => {
                //ok
            })
            .catch(errors => {
                //not ok
            });

        },

    }

}
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Medical;

class MedicalController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request); works fine

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        dd($request); // does not return any values

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Manually setting the method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457#issuecomment-239451567) of request may help solving the problem.

---

I have tried many times to send binary data via `axios` and I discovered that the best method is by wrapping your data in a `FormData` object. Please have the following code as reference:

```
<template>
    <input @change="uploadFile" type="file">
</template>

<script>
 // ...
    uploadFile: function(event) 
    {
        var data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', event.target.files[0]); // can be a list of files
            // data.append('_method', 'PATCH'); should not be necessary

        // post
        axios.patch('/url-here', data)

        // response
        .then(response=>{
            this.toast('File uploaded! '+ response.data.name)
        })
    },
 // ..
</script>
```

Then in your `Controller` parse the data as you normally would:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|file|max:4096|...',
        ]);

        dd ($validated);
    }
```

Comment: I posted one silly piece of code. Please recheck it in case you already viewed my answer.

Comment: Awesome! I advise to post the solution you came up with and accept it as answer for it may be of good use for further visitors :)